# Unable to move file in container using dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers

I have a very simple dockerfile which i have written but unfortunately, it is failing while executing below command in dockerfile:-

```
RUN ["cp -r", "node_modules/dir1/test/*", "/app"]
```

Below is the Error message which i get:-

```
OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"cp -r\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
```

I have also tried using "mv" command instead of "cp" but with no success.

I don't want to move the complete folder but all the content of folder. As said if i execute below command it works but, it moves the directory:-

```
RUN ["cp -r", "node_modules/dir1/test", "/app"]
```

Any Suggestions.? I have tried looking into many questions but, couldnt find a concrete explanation and the answer on how we can do it.?

Thanks,
Vishesh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally in Unix-like operating systems, commands are broken up into "words".  When you use the JSON-array syntax for `RUN`, `ENTRYPOINT`, and `CMD` directives, you're explicitly specifying what the words are, and they're not further processed split up.

In particular when you run

```
RUN ["cp -r", "node_modules/dir1/test/*", "/app"]
```

it looks for a command named `cp -r` in the usual places, where the command name includes a space and a hyphen.  It won't find `/bin/cp` which doesn't have a space and a hyphen and there isn't a `/bin/cp\ -r`.  If this were to work, it would also pass its first argument containing a `*` in the filename, which will also fail.

The easiest solution here is to not use the JSON-array form.  This will implicitly run a shell (the command is wrapped in `/bin/sh -c`) which will split words and expand globs for you.

```
RUN cp -r node_modules/dir1/test/* /app
```

If you didn't need the wildcard, you need to manually split `cp` and `-r` into separate words

```
RUN ["cp", "-r", "node_modules/dir1/test", "/app"]
```

Comment: Thanks for Explanation David . It makes sense and gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to check if the `cp` command is available. Once it's available you need to add `/.` for copying the content only.

```
RUN ["cp -r", "node_modules/dir1/test/.", "/app/"]
```

**Snapshot from the documentation.**
[image]